# Stop redirect from iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Is their a way I could stop a redirect in a iframe?

**Example**

```
<iframe
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DmiMpABb804"
width="50%" height="50%">
</iframe>
```

Comment: What kind of redirect? If the content of the iframe redirected to another page? Or the whole page? Or are you talking about a redirect when you click on something inside of the iframe? (And then again, only the content or the whole page?)

Comment: in `iframe ` ads shows. and when some one click them its redial to ads page. how i can stop that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `sandbox=""` property to the `iframe`